# Not able to update the deleted user in the Browser using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I Have Json File which Contains an array of data...I am able to delete the Object from that Array and able to see in console also , But in the Browser when I click on "deleteUser" it is not getting deleted and not showing the updated list ...Can anyone help me in this ? Thanks in Advance..

Here the Dashboard file

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../Common/data.json';
import { Editbutton } from '../NormalDeelte/Editbutton'


const Dashboard1 = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {data.map((lists) => (
                        <div>
                            <li>{lists.firstName}</li>
                            <li>{lists.lastName}</li>

                            <Editbutton id={lists.id} />
                        </div>

                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard1
```

here is the EditButton

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import data from '../Common/data.json';

export const Editbutton = (props) => {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState(data)
        //console.log(users);
    const deleteUser =(id) =>{
           //console.log(id)
           let newuers = users.filter((myUser)=> id !==myUser.id);
          // console.log(newuers);
            setUsers(newuers);
    }

  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => {deleteUser(props.id)}}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

here is the Json file

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Jason",
        "lastName": "rey",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Manson",
        "lastName": "hena",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jena",
        "lastName": "Manson",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "firstName": "roy",
        "lastName": "butler",
        "id": 4
    }
]
```

Comment: You're setting the users state, but you're not actually using that state anywhere.

Comment: @Nathan What changes I need to do , Can you help me in this?

Comment: You're thinking about state wrong, I'd recommend reading the documentation on it. But if you want a quick fix, remove the EditButton component, and use the `useState` directly in your Dashboard component. Then, instead of having `data.map(...)`, do `users.map(...)`

Comment: State is local to the component, changing the users state won't affect the data variable in its parent component (you're not mutating the data or anything, you're updating a copy of it).

Comment: @Nathan , But actually  EditButton Component should be the child Component of Dashboard , So Here I need to send the Id through props and then in the edit button i need to filter and delete, So In this Secenaro , WHat should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution for this

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import data from '../Common/data.json';

    export const Editbutton = ({props,deleteUser}) => {
    
      return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={(props) => {deleteUser(props.id)}}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      )
    }

import React,{useState} from 'react';
import data from '../Common/data.json';
import { Editbutton } from '../NormalDeelte/Editbutton'


const Dashboard1 = () => {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState(data)

    const deleteUser =(id) =>{
          //console.log(id);
          let newuers = users.filter((myUser)=> id !==myUser.id);
          //console.log(newuers);
          setUsers(newuers);
    }


    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {users.map((lists) => (
                        <div>
                            <li>{lists.firstName}</li>
                            <li>{lists.lastName}</li>

                            <Editbutton id={lists.id} deleteUser={() => {deleteUser(lists.id)}} />
                        </div>

                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default Dashboard1
```